# How to add text to a cell of a tablewidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qt5.3

I have a tablewidget in my application. It has 2 columns including filename and filepath. I want to add text to this tablewidget with a pushbutton and use this text to do some operation. How to do this?

Comment: I need some functions I think but I don't know which functions should I use?

Comment: did you tried to google something? like "qtablewidget add row"? have you read some of the results?

Comment: Yes, but I have a problem. I need to add text to the cell, not item. In the results in google, it shows the method with item.

Comment: yes, you can't add text directly to a `QTableWidget` cell, you have to do through a `QTableWidgetItem` (one cell at a time)

Comment: I'm getting the filenames from a directory and add them to the tablewidget. So, how can I do that by using QTableWidgetItem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't add text (`QString`) directly to a `QTableWidget`, you must first create a `QTableWidgetItem` and then insert it into the desired cell. Example:

```
// create a new qtablewidget
QTableWidget tablewidget;

// our tablewidget has 2 columns
tablewidget.setColumnCount(2);

// we insert a row at position 0 because the tablewidget is still empty
tablewidget.insertRow(0);

// we add the items to the row we added
tablewidget.setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("first row, first column"));
tablewidget.setItem(0, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("first row, second column"));
```

if you have more columns, the way is the same

if you want to add more rows (and this is good even with the first), you can use a generic

```
tablewidget.insertRow(tablewidget.rowCount());
```

which always add a new row at the end of the table (append);

more difficult: this should explain how `insertRow()` is different (and powerful) than a non-existent `appendRow()`

```
QTableWidget tablewidget;
tablewidget.setColumnCount(2);

// we insert a row at position 0 because the tablewidget is still empty
tablewidget.insertRow(tablewidget.rowCount());

tablewidget.setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("first row, first column"));
tablewidget.setItem(0, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("first row, second column"));

// "append" new row at the bottom with rowCount()
tablewidget.insertRow(tablewidget.rowCount());
tablewidget.setItem(1, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("second row, first column"));
tablewidget.setItem(1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("second row, second column"));

// we insert a "new" second row pushing the old row down
tablewidget.insertRow(1);
tablewidget.setItem(1, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("this push the"));
tablewidget.setItem(1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("second row down"));
```